# Distributed transactions SQL Server <-> MySql. Exception: MySQL Connector/Net does not currently support distributed transactions

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, mysql-connector

I have to sync some data from a SQL Server 2008 DB to a MySql DB.
I'm using C# and EF to manage data.

Flow is: read unsynced rows from SQL server, convert the entries (through the class EntitiesConverter) to MySql db entities, add rows to MySql, mark SQL rows as synced (and save changes on both contexts).

Code:

```
public static int SyncAttivitaToHiPlan(int start, int? end)
    {

        var options = new TransactionOptions();
        options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable;

        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
        {
            //MySql ObjectContext
            var hpContext = new hiplanEntities1();

            //SQL Server ObjectContext
            var otoContext = new OTOCOMMEntities1();

            var otoProvider = OtoCommEntitiesProvider.GetInstance();

            IEnumerable<Attivita> attivitaEntries;

            if (end == null)
                attivitaEntries = otoProvider.GetUnsyncedAttivita(start);
            else
                attivitaEntries = otoProvider.GetUnsyncedAttivita(start, (int)end);

            var tvavalavs = new ConcurrentQueue<tvavalav>();
            //ObjectContext is not thread-safe
            //attivitaEntries.AsParallel().AsOrdered().ForAll((a) => tvavalavs.Enqueue(EntitiesConverter.BuildTvavalavFromAttivita(a)));
            foreach (var a in attivitaEntries)
            {
                tvavalavs.Enqueue(EntitiesConverter.BuildTvavalavFromAttivita(a));
            }


            foreach (var t in tvavalavs)
            {
                hpContext.tvavalav.AddObject(t);
            }

          //  attivitaEntries.AsParallel().ForAll((a) => a.Synced = true);
            foreach (var a in attivitaEntries)
            {
                a.Synced = true;
            }
            hpContext.SaveChanges();
            otoContext.SaveChanges();

        }
        return 0; //TODO: return the number of synced rows.
    }

}
```

When I try it, I get a MySql Connector Exception: "MySQL Connector/Net does not currently support distributed transactions."

How can I solve this? Is there a way to do this in a single transaction ("virtual" singles transaction, as I am working with 2 differnt db) without getting that exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I solve this?

My car is broken, how can I solve this?

Sorry, the cnnector is not according to spec and does not Support distributed Transactions. EIther find a way to do that without them, or fix the connector, or use one that does Support them. Simply like that.

Separate Transactions are complex - a DTC is a VEY complexy beast. Yes, 2 Transactions work. Unless they fail - i.e. a machine or the Network goes down, then you have half open Transactions (one commited, the other rolled back).

YOu COULD do a merge mechanism - mark the class inthe source only as symced when this is done (after commiting mysql) AND
write the target part so it "updates" or sees that rows already were there, but that will slow thigns down.

Then you can work around it.